# 404 HEAD issue when creating AWS Elasticsearch index

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am trying to create my first index using python and I keep getting a 404 index not found exception.  Here is the current code:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'host_url', 'port': 443, 'use_ssl': True, 'timeout': 300}])

if es.indices.exists('test_logs'):
    es.indices.delete(index = 'test_logs')

request_body = {
    'settings': {
        'number_of_shards': 2,
        'number_of_relicas': 2
    },
    'mappings': {
        'logs': {
            'properties': {
                'date': { 'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'date' },
                'time': { 'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'time' },
                'request': { 'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string' },
                'status': { 'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'int' },
                'agent': { 'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
}

es.indices.create(index = 'test_logs', ignore = [400, 404], body = request_body, request_timeout = 30)
```

EDIT:  I have changed some things and now I get a different error.  I have updated my code and title for the new issue.  Here is my output:

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py:54: UserW
arning: Connecting to host_url using SSL with verify_certs=False is insecure.
  'Connecting to %s using SSL with verify_certs=False is insecure.' % host)
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarn
ing: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is
strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
HEAD /test_logs [status:404 request:0.902s]
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:789: InsecureRequestWarn
ing: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is
strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What does the HEAD /test_logs 404 mean?

Comment: That's probably just how it tests if the index already exists.

Comment: I have logged into AWS and refreshed multiple times but I still do not see the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed my connection to:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = host,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection,
    port = 443,
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = False)
```

Works fine now.  Do not know why the previous one failed.